# Creating realistic plastic with parting lines?

Tags: modeling, materials

I'm trying to understand how to model/render realistic plastic in Blender. The part I couldn't figure out how to create yet is the parting line (the line where the plastic mold connected during the molding/injection process, like in this image:
[image]

Can anyone explain how to achieve this efficiently in Blender?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it, you could make the parting with a simple extrude (but you could as well do it with a *Bump* node). To make the plastic material you could mix a *Diffuse* with a *Glossy* node. To create the small wave bumps and the logo, use a *MixRGB* (*Add* mode) to mix a *Wave* texture with an *Image Texture*, and plug the *MixRGB* into the *Normal* sockets of the *Diffuse* and *GLossy*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: final]

### Procedural method

**Line:**

Create a line around your ball and make it as a group with ability to change position on the Z axis and width.

[image: line_nodes]

[image: line_gif]

2. Combine **3 Line groups** and add some noise to them. I've used only simple noise, but you can be a lot more creative with it. Make it as **Bump** map.

I've added also some **Roughness** and more **Bumps** on the surface of the ball.

[image: nodes]

Comment: Wow! Looks amazing, even though above my current knowledge of node setups and material design. Many thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that with bumps maps or normal maps, and simple difuse and roughness/ glossiness texture. though you can model those "parting lines" and then bake then into a texture, and also you can try to use a clouds texture with some tweaks with nodes maybe to make the small bumps in the surface, or do hand painting with a alpha texture.